# Shift of dates not working as expected

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, date

I have a file with records in this format :

```
D20220327,S2927,977,1

D20220328,S2927,977,1

D20220329,S2927,977,1

D20220330,S2927,977,1

D20220331,S2927,977,1

D20220401,S2927,977,1

D20220402,S2927,977,1

D20220403,S2927,977,1

D20220404,S2927,977,1
```

However after applying the transformation to shift these to 7 days back in the past, it is not working for dates from 28th Mar to 03rd April, However same code logic is working fine on 27th March & 04th April. I am not able to figure why this is not working for one week only.
This is the output

```
D20220320,S2927,977,1 -- correct

D20220320,S2927,977,1 -- incorrect 

D20220321,S2927,977,1 -- incorrect

D20220322,S2927,977,1 -- incorrect

D20220323,S2927,977,1 -- incorrect

D20220324,S2927,977,1 -- incorrect

D20220325,S2927,977,1 -- incorrect

D20220326,S2927,977,1 -- incorrect

D20220328,S2927,977,1 -- correct
```

Logic used here is :

```
    BEGIN {
        OFS = FS = ","
}

{
        t = mktime(sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00",
                substr($1,2,4),
                substr($1,6,2),
                substr($1,8,2)));

        $1 = substr($1,1,1) strftime("%Y%m%d", t - 7*24*60*60)

        print
}
```

Comment: --GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: that gawk version is 11 years out of date and missing a lot of important bug fixes and new features, you should get a newer version. We're currently on version 5.1.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your calculations are done in local time, and you are affected by the switch over to daylight saving on the 27th of March.

To do the calculation in UTC time instead (Unix timestamps are not in local time), using a recent release of GNU `awk`, make sure that you pass an extra `1` as a last argument to `mktime()`:

```c
t = mktime(sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00",
        substr($1,2,4),
        substr($1,6,2),
        substr($1,8,2)), 1);
```

This is a GNU `awk` extension available in GNU `awk` release 4.2.0+.

As an alternative, you could instead avoid using a time around midnight (UTC) as your reference time of day:

```c
t = mktime(sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 12 00 00",
        substr($1,2,4),
        substr($1,6,2),
        substr($1,8,2)));
```

This would make it work in older GNU `awk` implementations and in any other `awk` that has the required functions.

Yet another alternative is to make the script run with an altered local time zone:

```bsh
TZ=UTC awk -f script.awk inputfile
```

This sets the `TZ` environment variable to `UTC` for the execution of the `awk` script, which alters the time zone used by the `mktime()` and related functions.

Comment: That is available from 4.2.0 onwards only - https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2017-10/msg00000.html

Comment: @they Thanks.. However i still have two doubts. 
1. Which local time was it using for calculations given that server itself is in UK timezone ?
2. Using 12:00:00 instead of 00:00:00 -- will this be making changes to any of the dates not affected by clock change ?

Comment: @AayushJain 1) It would have used the local time of the system on which it was running.  2) It strikes me as an easy thing to test. Just run your code twice and use `diff` to compare the results. That would be better than having to trust my word (because I might have overlooked something).  However, as long as the code is not run in a +/-12h timezone, it would probably be ok.

Comment: @AayushJain I'm also investigating a third way to fix this. Check back in a few minutes.

Comment: Using noon instead of midnight each day is key in all such date calculations. Using midnight is an extremely common mistake. I don;t think I've ever seen `"%.2d"` used to produce 0-padded output, normally `"%02d"` is used. Is `.` also guaranteed to pad with `0`s instead of blanks? I don't know....

Comment: @EdMorton `%.2d` is guaranteed to zero fill to two digits of width. I will see if I can find a reference to where I've seen this being stated as the preferred format compared to `%02d`.

Comment: Thanks. I'd be interested to know why `%02d` exists in that case since that's all it's for and so if that''s a subset of what `%.2d` does then it seems pointless for `%02d` to exist. So far I've found a reference to `%.2d` (https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers) that says `Minimum number of digits to print` so it'd make sense if any digits added were leading zeros.
`

Comment: @EdMorton I haven't found the reference I was looking for, but `%02d` seems rather pointless, yes.  With `%n.md`, you can define the field width with `n` and the precision (number of digits to zero fill to) with `m`, so that e.g. `%4.2d` creates a 4 character wide string (at least), with at least two right-justified digits (zero-filled if the given number to format is less than 10).

Comment: Looks like `.` and `0` behave very differently with other modifiers, e.g. `%.2g` vs `%02g` and while `0` always left-pads with `0`s, `.` sometimes pads but sometimes truncates depending on the char that follows it so I guess each has it's uses.

Comment: @EdMorton Ah, I see. Yes, I never thought about other data types than decimal integers.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ D <( (\d**4)(\d**2)(\d**2) )> \, /{ "$0-$1-$2".Date.earlier(:7days).Str.subst("-", :g); }/;'
```

Sample Input (blank lines removed):

```
D20220327,S2927,977,1
D20220328,S2927,977,1
D20220329,S2927,977,1
D20220330,S2927,977,1
D20220331,S2927,977,1
D20220401,S2927,977,1
D20220402,S2927,977,1
D20220403,S2927,977,1
D20220404,S2927,977,1
```

Sample Output:

```
D20220320,S2927,977,1
D20220321,S2927,977,1
D20220322,S2927,977,1
D20220323,S2927,977,1
D20220324,S2927,977,1
D20220325,S2927,977,1
D20220326,S2927,977,1
D20220327,S2927,977,1
D20220328,S2927,977,1
```

Briefly, Raku's linewise (autoprinting) `-pe` flags are used, in conjunction with the familiar `s///` operator. Digits are captured into match variables `$0`, `$1`, and `$2` with parens, and capture markers `<( … )>` are employed to drop all other elements of the match.

In the replacement, Raku executes code inside a `{ … }` block. The `$0`, `$1`, and `$2` captures are stringified with appropriate dashes (`-`), and this string is recognized as a `Date` object, upon which the `earlier(:7days)` method can be called. [Note: some users may find writing `earlier(days => 7)` to be a more familiar syntax--either form works]. Once the `Date` object is set back 7 days, its `Str`-ingified and `subst` is used to remove the dashes (`-`) in the return.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/Date
https://docs.raku.org/routine/Dateish
https://raku.org